# How to fix the alignment issue of the header with the rest of the bootstrap form controls?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3. Here is my code

```css
.divisionify {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 2px solid gray;
}

.form-title {
  position: relative;
  color: #7cc0e1;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="form-title">Apply for Plan</div>
    <div class="divisionify"></div>

    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="institution-type" class="control-label">Type of institution</label>
        <div class="">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="institution-type" placeholder="Type of institution">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Apply</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

And it produces this layout

[image]

You can see the title 'Apply for Plan' does not align with the form controls on the left hand side.

it is because of these settings by Bootstrap

```
margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px;
```

[image]

I can fix this issue by adding them too to my css class `.form-title` and `.divisionify`

However is there a better way to fix the alignment?

This is my desired layout

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why not just override the Bootstrap styles with your own?

Add this to your code:

```
.form-group {
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it gonna work. However isn't it generally a bad idea to use `~important`?

Comment: People like to say things like: *never use `!important`*, *never use inline styles*, *never use tables for layout*, etc. These sorts of statements are generally simplistic and exaggerated.

Comment: I agree that `!important` should not be used as a substitute for writing good quality code. You should always use specificity and the cascade to apply your rules correctly. But keep in mind that `!important` is in the spec. It exists for a reason. One good reason for using `!important` is to override code over which you have no control.

Comment: I've never had to use `!important` in code I've authored. But it has come in handy on many occasions when I want to apply styles to third-party tools, such as search, translation and calendars.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: You shouldn't use `!important` unless you're sure you have to. It does terrible things to the cascade, the specificity, the rules in the user stylesheet etc. Its effects are much worse than using inline styles or tables!

Answer (score 1):

Give a padding of the `left` and `right` of the `.form-title` and `.divisionify`

```
.divisionify {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
.form-title{
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

[Check live](http://codepen.io/sifulislam/pen/EZqyBq)

Comment: I have already mentioned this inside the question. I am asking if there is better alternative.

Comment: yes! you call column class on `form-group` . like `form-group col-md-12` .

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using the `!important` thing is that everything will end up being important to you. I would use parent-to-child calls example:

`#father.child{margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px;}`.

With this, you will govern without using the `!important`. Think that using the `!important` you are going to change the default responsive of Bootstrap to the whole page for this case.

DOC:[What are the implications of using "!important" in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional id to the elements and style them according to your wish. In this way you can avoid `!important`. This is the way preferred by me.

**Edited code snippet**

```css
.divisionify {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 2px solid gray;
  
}

.form-title {
  position: relative;
  color: #7cc0e1;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
#applyPlan {
margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px;
}
#division {
 margin-left: -15px;
 margin-right: -15px;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div id= "applyPlan" class="form-title">Apply for Plan</div>
    <div id="division" class="divisionify"></div>

    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="institution-type" class="control-label">Type of institution</label>
        <div class="">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="institution-type" placeholder="Type of institution">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Apply</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```